# Cant use variable from React Context to access value of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, object, react-context

I'm encountering a very strange but seemingly simple problem.

I do have an object called `vatRates` which looks like this:

```
const vatRates = {
  "AD": 0.00,
  "CZ": 1.21,
  "RO": 1.19,
  "DE": 1.19,
  "RS": 0.00,
  "RU": 0.00,
  "SE": 1.25,
  "SI": 1.22,
  "SK": 1.20,
  "TR": 0.00,
  "UA": 0.00,
  "US": 0.00
}
```

an I'm getting a constant called `countryCode` from my React `Context`, countryCode has a default value 'DE' and then during initialization of the context changed to "CZ".

`countryCode` is never null or undefined.

In my component I want to get the value of the `countryCode` in the `vatRates` object.

The code should be simple right?

```
console.log(vatRates[countryCode])
```

but it only works when `countryCode` has the default value of "DE" even though the key "CZ" exists on the object.

here a console log of what I'm getting. I really don't know why this simple thing doesn't work.

[image]

When I access the object like this manually it works fine.

```
vatRates["CZ"]
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-nobel-i9vouj?file=/src/App.js) which shows the problem

Comment: You've explained the problem you're observing, but given us no information on how to solve it. Where is the code for the context provider and where you use the context? Please include a [mre]

Comment: @BrianThompson you can checkout this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-nobel-i9vouj?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

everything with your context is OK.
The problem is there are some whitespaces in value from API.

Just use `vatRates[countryCode.trim()]` or even better in context:

```
 const fetchCountryCode = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country");
      const countryCode = await res.text();

      return countryCode.trim();
 };
```